# How to change the text color of rightBarButtonItem of AdobeUXImageEditorViewController

Tags: adobecreativesdk

When AdobeUXImageEditorViewController is launched, the text color of rightBarButtonItem "Done" is always blue, please check the attached image.
How can I change the text color to white?
Please check the following code of how did I try to set the color.

```
editorViewController = AdobeUXImageEditorViewController(image: image)
editorViewController!.delegate = self
presentViewController(editorViewController!, animated: true) {
    [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
    strongSelf.editorViewController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
```

[image: phone screenshot]

Best Regards,
Haibin

Comment: Would you mind including any code showing how you are setting the color?

Comment: @Noah, I have added the code of how did I try to set the color. Please check the it in the question description. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, the color of image SDK can be customized by ImageSDKCostomizer, this is an application on MAC which is released together with image SDK.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2tX6.png)